# Shell script for executing programs within a loop and checking their exit values

Tags: shell-script, exit-status

How do I do this in a shell script:

```
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {

   run applicationA
   run applicationB
   if (retvalFromApplicationB!=0) {continue;}
   else {pipe ouptut (stdout) from applicationB to (stdin of) (and start) applicationC}
   if (retvalFromApplicationC!=0) {break;}
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh -
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 1000 ]; do
  cmdA
  cmdB > tempfile || continue
  cmdC < tempfile || break
  i=$((i + 1))
done
rm -f tempfile
```

If you can't litter the current directory with temp files, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 1000 ]; do
  cmdA 3>&- 4<&-
  tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
  exec 3> "$tmp" 4< "$tmp"
  rm -f "$tmp"
  cmdB >&3 3>&- 4<&- || continue
  cmdC <&4 3>&- 4<&- < tempfile || break
  i=$((i + 1))
done
exec 3>&- 4<&-
rm -f tempfile
```

Whatever you do, you'll need to store that output somewhere as you can't get the exit status of `cmdB` until it has terminated.

You could store it in memory instead. If `cmdB`'s output is text, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 1000 ]; do
  cmdA
  output=$(cmdB > tempfile && echo .) || continue
  output=${output%.}
  printf %s "$output" | cmdC || break
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

If `printf` is not built in your `/bin/sh` (for instance if you've installed `mksh` or `yash` and made it `sh`), that will fail for output larger than 128KiB.

Or you could use `perl` instead:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
  system "cmdA";
  $output = `cmdB`;
  next if $?;
  open TO_C, "|-", "cmdC" or last;
  print TO_C $output;
  close TO_C;
  last if $?;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If an exception is thrown by any of the applications (for example out_of_range in a vector) will the loop stop, or do I have to take care of that myself?

Comment: @Bwawhwmopoloin, what the shell sees is the exit status of the process. _Exception_ is a paradigm of some programming languages. If those _exceptions_ cause the process running the application compiled from the source in that programming language to die with a non-zero exit status, then yes, the shell (the `||` operator above) or `perl` (when we check for `$?`) will take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if your shell is bash, then $? is also available.  From the man page: "Expands to the status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline" which is a way of saying that it holds the exit status of the last executed process.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) 
    {
       run applicationA
       retvalFromApplicationA = $?

       run applicationB
       retvalFromApplicationB = $?

       if (retvalFromApplicationB!=0) {continue;}
       else {pipe ouptut (stdout) from applicationB to (stdin of) (and start) applicationC}
       if (retvalFromApplicationC!=0) {break;}
    }
```

The code above doesn't capture the exit status of applicationC, but it would be something like:

```
applicationB | applicationC
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

That works because the last process to exit would be applicationC.  If you're using a different shell, check the man/info page.  There are other ways to do it with the && and || operators as well.